# How to retrieve a single item from nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am reading from a file with data like this:

```
{"day" :"Monday", "alarm":"on", "kids":"School" , "work":"days"}
{"day" :"Tuesday", "alarm":"on", "kids":"School" , "work":"days"}
{"day" :"Wednesday", "alarm":"on", "kids":"School" , "work":"days"}
{"day" :"Thursday", "alarm":"on", "kids":"School" , "work":"nights"}
{"day" :"Friday", "alarm":"on", "kids":"School" , "work":"nights"}
{"day" :"Saturday", "alarm":"off", "kids":"Dance" , "work":"overtime"}
{"day" :"Sunday", "alarm":"off", "kids":"Soccer" , "work":"off"}
```

I am putting the data into an dictionary, then evaluating the dictionary for some condition and placing that dictionary into another dictionary like so:

```
import ast
o=open('schedule.txt','rb')
day_={}
for lines in o:
    dict_={}
    dict_= ast.literal_eval(lines)
    if dict_['day']=='Monday':
        day_['1']=dict_.items()
    elif dict_['day']=='Tuesday':
        day_['2']=dict_.items()
    elif dict_['day']=='Wednesday':
        day_['3']=dict_.items()
    elif dict_['day']=='Thursday':
        day_['4']=dict_.items()
    elif dict_['day']=='Friday':
        day_['5']=dict_.items()
    elif dict_['day']=='Saturday':
        day_['6']=dict_.items()
    elif dict_['day']=='Sunday':
        day_['7']=dict_.items()
    else:
        print('there was an error')
o.close()
print day_.items()
#this seems to work properly
```

Now if I only want to find out what the kids are doing on day 4, how do I do this?
Or is there an easier way to hold the data for future reference within the program?

Comment: realized that `dict_.items()` is a list not a dict.  Now that I changed it so I'm storing it as a dict rather then a list, it seems to be working using part of @Sven Marnach's solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using a dictionary to map weekday names to numbers.  To extract the `"kids"` item of the record for day 4, you can use `result[4]["kids"]`:

```
days = {"Monday": 1, "Tuesday": 2, "Wednesday": 3, "Thursday": 4,
        "Friday": 5, "Saturday": 6, "Sunday": 7}
result = {}
with open('schedule.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        d = ast.literal_eval(line)
        result[days[d["day"]]] = d
print result[4]["kids"]
```

Comment: @Scott: Unless there is some hidden meaning in the "1", "2", "3"... strings, why not leave the weekday names in place? Like in, `result["Thursday"]["kids"]`

Comment: I like your solution of mapping the days like that, however this is a simplified example I've been using to test and get things working on a different problem in a weather script, and I have nothing to map like that.  In the weather script I'm using the date rather then a number for the key, and I want to be able to get a piece of information for a specific date.  Works the same way, but this is just simplified.

Comment: There's also a spelling mistake in the OP: Wedensday